# Convert a List <String> to a blob

Tags: apex

I trying to convert a List  to a blob but am unable to do so.

I have used the following syntax:
encodedData is a base64 encoded List

when I run: `Blob.valueOf(encodedData);` I received the following error: `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void valueOf(List<String>) from the type Blob`

Please let me know if anyone has ideas!

Comment: What is it you expect to be the output? Typically you would only encode a single string. The error tells you everything you need to know. But your question post above needs to fill in some gaps.

Comment: You could use `String.join()` on the List to pass into `Blob.valueOf()` but you'd need to split it again when calling `toString()` of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys!
I went with the following approach:

1. Transformed the `List <String>` to a Map <String, Object> as I am dealing with JSON for my business use case.

```
Map <String, Object> surveyJSON = new Map <String, Object>();
surveyJson.put('Survey_Name__c', d.Survey_Name__c);
surveyJson.put('Survey_Questions__c', surveyQuestions);
surveyJSON.put('Survey_Choices__c', surveyChoices);
```

2. Once I created my new map I was able to use the `valueOf` method on the `blob` object.

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.Body = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(surveyJson));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using json.serialize(encodedData) like this this.

```
List<String> encodedData = new List<String>{'string1','String2'};
blob blob1;
String req = json.serialize(encodedData);
blob1 = blob.valueOf(req);
system.debug(req);
system.debug(blob1);
```